# how to make a pandas take values from multiple lists within a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, nlp

I have a folder with multiple html files.I want the code to go through each and every file and pick the subject verb object triplets using nlp.  I then want pandas to list all of them under the headings of subject verb object for all the files together in one data frame. The problem I face is panda lists only the the subject verb object from the last file and not the first two. When I print the sub_verb_obj in loop it shows 3 lists within a list. But pandas does not pick the 3 lists triplets. Can someone tell me what mistake am I doing?

````
sub_verb_obj=[]
folder_path = 'C:/Users/user3/.ipynb_checkpoints/xyz/xyz_2018'
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path, '*.html')):
  with open(filename, 'r',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    pat = f.read()
    
    doc=nlp(text)
    text_ext = textacy.extract.subject_verb_object_triples(doc)
    sub_verb_obj=list(text_ext)
    
sao=pd.DataFrame(sub_verb_obj)
sao.columns=['subject','verb','object']
sao=sao.set_index('subject')
print(sao)```

how can I make sure the pandas lists all the subject verb object from all the files in a folder in a single dataframe?
````

Answer (score 1):

Because your data looks to be a list of tuples each iteration, and that worked for a single run, I'd suggest building a dataframe each loop, storing it in a list, then concatenating the list of dataframes

```
df_hold_list=[]
folder_path = 'C:/Users/user3/.ipynb_checkpoints/xyz/xyz_2018'
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path, '*.html')):
  with open(filename, 'r',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    pat = f.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(pat, 'html.parser')
    claim_section = soup.find_all('section', attrs={"itemprop":"claims"})
    str_sect  =  claim_section[0]
    claim_text=str_sect.get_text()
    #print(str(type(claim_section))) 
    clean_lower=claim_text.lower()
    text=clean_lower
    doc=nlp(text)
    text_ext = textacy.extract.subject_verb_object_triples(doc)
    sub_verb_obj=list(text_ext)
    df_hold_list.append(pd.DataFrame(sub_verb_obj)) # add each new dataframe here

sao=pd.concat(df_hold_list, axis=0) # this should concat all dfs on top of one another using axis=0
sao.columns=['subject','verb','object'] # change your columns on teh final df
sao=sao.set_index('subject')
print(sao)
```

Comment: ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 330 elements, new values have 3 elements  .. Pandas cant still pick it up

Comment: without data and actual error stack, it's difficult to help you. can you post the data exactly from sub_verb_obj?

Comment: for a single patent i use the same code but without the loop. I get an output with 3 columns which read as subject verb object and several rows. Now for a folder which has multiple files I still want pandas to have 3 columns of same headings subject verb object but just update the rows one after the other.